# Put UIActivityIndicator over UIMapView

Tags: mkmapview, spinner

I would like to put a UIActivityIndicator in the center of my UIMapView. I have setup plenty of spinners before, but not sure what I'm missing about the MapView that is making this difficult.

The real issue seems to be that when I try to place the UIActivityIndicator onto the UIMapView in Interface Builder, it doesn't stick or it breaks the Map View.

Comment: The issue actually appears to be related to the fact I have a NavigationController and ViewController defined in the xib. I was able to create a basic MKMapView with a spinner, but something I'm not grasping about the Nav/ViewController setup.

Comment: Can you share your code?